# How should I explain that I'm reneging on acceptance of a job offer

Tags: recruitment, negotiation, employment-agreement

There are two companies that are willing to employ me as a programmer. The first one offered higher payment but the other one is more interesting for me. I decided to accept the higher payment company so I emailed my decision to both companies and gave personal information to first one. After that, the interesting company called me again and reconsidered they offer. They are still offering less than the first company, but I would like to work for them so I agreed.

I didn't sign a contract yet, but they will probably ask why I'm doing it. Now what could be the best way to explain to the first company that I am actually withdrawing my word I gave them?

Comment: "I received another offer that I felt was a better fit."

Comment: What do you think about this: "Dear candidate, we found another candidate who was a better fit for the job, so we would be withdrawing the offer we made you."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tell them politely, but succinctly, that you've received another offer which you're more interested in.  "A better fit" as Chris G says, is a good way to put it.  They won't be upset (or shouldn't be, anyway) - this sort of thing happens all the time.

Whatever you do, just make sure you tell them *soon.*  Right now, the first company thinks they've filled this position, so they'll be taking down job postings, informing other candidates that the position is gone, etc, etc.  The sooner they know that you've changed your mind, the less problematic it will be to find someone else.  They may very well have one or two "runner-ups" *right now* that they can contact; once they know they need to.

Assuming this all just happened today, you could probably wait until Monday with little detriment to anyone concerned.  However, I personally would fire off an e-mail tonight to the hiring manager at the first company - that way they can hit the ground running next week, so to speak.